# Possibly-undefined argument to PHP function

Tags: php, arrays, isset

In displaying values retrieved from a database, values that may or may not exist, my PHP code has a lot of this:

```
if ( isset( $data['a'] ) )
    $a = number_format( $data['a'] );
else
    $a = '–';
if ( isset( $data['b'] ) )
    $b = number_format( $data['b'] );
else
    $b = '–';
```

(Simplified for example; `$data['a']` is actually things like `$data[$date][$part]['errors']`.) This is followed later by `<td><?= $a ?></td>` and `<td><?= $b ?></td>`.

Using `?:` instead of `if` makes the code vertically more compact but uglier. I'd like to put this in a function so I can have

```
$a = someFunction( $data['a'] );
$b = someFunction( $data['b'] );
```

instead, which is much nicer. But having an unset variable as a function argument causes two warnings, one for the unset variable and then another for a missing function argument. If I make the obvious function and call it with `@`...

```
function formatIfAvail( $num, $dec = 0 )
{
    if ( isset( $num ) )
        return number_format( $num, $dec );
    return '–';
}

....

$a = @formatIfAvail( $data['a'] );
```

...it *works*, but this seems like a bad solution. **Is there a way to do this without any `@`?** If PHP had the C++ preprocessor I would use a #define something like this...

```
#define NUMFMT( n, d )    ( isset( n ) ? number_format( n, d ) : '–' )

....

$a = NUMFMT( $data['a'], 0 );
```

...but of course, it doesn't.

Comment: use the @ in the variable, not in the function. someFunction(@$data['a'])

Comment: there's no way to supress warnings other than using @ or the global way with error reporting features

Comment: How come you don't know if `data['a']` exists? You shouldn't gloss over input checking, especially if your data is user input.

Comment: Pass var by reference: formatIfAvail( & $num, $dec = 0 ). You wont get the notice.

Comment: Passing by call-time reference is deprecated

Comment: I tried `@` on the variable first, but then got one warning instead of two. It suppressed the warning about the array index not existing, but still gave the warning about a missing function argument.

Comment: @Ananth, Passing by reference works beautifully. And as I understand the docs, yes, call-time reference is deprecated and removed as of v5.4.0, but this is not call-time reference. Putting `&` in the function definition is okay, putting it in the function call is not.

Answer (score 0):

PHP emits warnings all over the language. As language, it has so many quirks and patches that making nice (good-looking) code is hard to impossible.

Said that, retrieving stuff like `$data['a']` or `$data[$date][$part]['errors']` will generate **at least** a warning if something went wrong in the value retrieval. I said "at least" because it usually depends on the implementation of the `ArrayAccess` interface (which defines usage of the square brackets operator), but the normal arrays will trigger a notice under the most common conditions.

So, you can turn off globally the notices and warnings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~(E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));
```

But perhaps you don't want to do that globally, but just locally to your call / code chunk. That's where the @ operators (syntactically ugly) comes to play. You can retrieve the value without a warning:

```
$myValue = @$data['a'];
$myValue = @$data[$date][$part]['errors'];
```

And you will not get any warning.

Under normal conditions you want to evaluate:

```
$myValue = @$data['a'] or $anotherValue;
```

To do so, in PHP you must use the *ugly* elvis operator (I share your opinion):

```
$myValue = @$data['a'] ?: $anotherValue;
```

because doing it with `or` (`||`) will give you a boolean value.

Additionally, you're stuck with another issue: You're not just trying to get a value "or" a default value. As I see in your code, you're trying to transform a value, if the value exists, or return a default value. **PHP does not support that** in a compressed way (I don't know about any language that supports it).

So you're stuck with what you know. I'd prefer like this:

```
function someFunction( $num, $dec = 0 )
{
    return ($number !== null) ? number_format( $num, $dec ) : '-';
}
$myVal = someFunction(@data['a'] ?: null);
```